# Is there a single place I could go in Italy to view birth records from Northern Italy from 1750-1850?

Tags: 19th-century, 18th-century, italy, research-travel

Where can I go (physically) in Italy to find records from the 1750-1850, for people who were born in the North of Italy?

I know that each city would have their registries, but I am missing the exact cities, and I do not think that going for all possible cities would be suitable.

So, is there a central place where I could find copies and so on?

Comment: I've expanded the title to be more explicit -- please check I've reflected what you need to know correctly.

Comment: Wasn't sure which century tag to add; so have added the later, "19th century" tag.

Comment: P.S. I don't know the answer to the question, but would like to travel in your suitcase when you do go!

Comment: Have you looked for Online sources e.g at FamilySearch.org? https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/list#page=1&countryId=1927178& dateRange=dateRange3 . What other online sources have you explored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two answers to your question based upon your time period.

> Civil authorities began registering births, marriages, and deaths in 1809 in many areas (1820 in Sicilia). By 1866 civil registration became law. After this date, virtually all individuals who lived in Italy were recorded.
>          https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Italy_Civil_Registration-_Vital_Records

That means that for at least 60 years of the century you specify, you will be looking at church records.

Once civil registration was in place, original records were retained by the registrar of the district.

> A copy of each record is sent to the procura della repubblica—which is similar to a district court in the United States—in the provincial capital. Because the civil records are legal documents and needed for government purposes, such as military draft, the duplicate is held by the tribunale (district court).
>
> You may need to use maps, gazetteers, and other geographic references to identify the place where your ancestor lived and the civil registration office that served that place. See Italy Maps and Italy Gazetteers for information on how to find civil registration offices.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.antenati.san.beniculturali.it/ Have records of birth, marriage, death and other kind of records digitalized (some of them indexed so you can search on them)
It begin in the early 1800s up to 1900

I found there my 6th upper ancestor

PD: This is one of the sources of familysearch.org